# wheel event delta not resetting to 0, but 1

Tags: javascript

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/joooo0/7yjdxpvu/

```
window.addEventListener('wheel', onWheel)

function onWheel(e){
  document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = e.deltaY
}
```

As you can see, the value gets higher the faster the scroll. 
But it won't reset to zero. It just goes back to 1 or -1. 
How can I set it to 0 when nothing *wheels*?

Edit: I'm on Chrome with MacBook

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47233755/6052427 could you try this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could set a timer for this:

```
window.addEventListener('wheel', onWheel)

let stopWheelTimer;
function onStopWheel(){
  document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = 0; 
}

function onWheel(e){
  console.log(e.deltaY);
  document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = e.deltaY;
  if(stopWheelTimer!==undefined){
    clearTimeout(stopWheelTimer)
  };
  stopWheelTimer = setTimeout(()=>onStopWheel(), 200);

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/69b37vfp/